# How to monitor and log Chef server and Chef client response time and network trafiic?

Tags: chef

I am very new to Chef Server and Chef Chef client. Also, new to Ruby in which Chef was written.

I have a problem monitoring the performance of chef server's response time when Chef client is running and getting information from it. By the way, our setup is 1 Chef server, 1 Chef client as the node and 1 Chef client for the workstation (where we execute knife commands).

Currently, our logs output information only contain the elapsed time after Chef client was run,

```
[root@sg8tb08208 chef]# chef-client
[2013-02-13T15:16:02+09:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.18.2 ***
```

..........more log info..................then

```
[2013-02-13T15:16:11+09:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 8.782384 seconds
```

but we also need to log or at least know the response time of the server and the network between them. Is this possible?

I have been scouring the web for 2 days now, and I can't even find a documentation about it. Or even, someone who tried it already. It would be very helpful even to know what is the average response time of a Chef server given n number of client/nodes connecting to it.

Your help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE:
I am trying to use revealcloud to monitor the server performance. This connects to CopperEgg. I have already set up the api_key and the proxy but I keep getting an error.

```
Error executing action `run` on resource 'script[revealcloud_install]'
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
 - !! Downloaded revealcloud binary does not match MD5
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20130214-1211-1xejv30-0" ----
```

Answer (score 3):

To examine the response times of each individual resource of your recipe, you can use [chef-handler-elapsed-time](https://github.com/jamesc/chef-handler-elapsed-time) to do some kind of profiling for those 8.782384 seconds.

For history of response times for the provision of multiple systems and statistics, you can use [chef-metrics](https://github.com/portertech/chef-metrics) and send all those cool metrics to a graphite.